# Algorithm for point distribution of traversal between 2 points on a line in time

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Not sure if this is best SO forum to post at, please suggest/move to more appropriate place otherwise. A synopsis of the problem 1st:

> Given a scenario where we have messages with data that define a user
>   moving from one x,y location to another (that would form a line), and
>   where for purposes of analysis/calculation, we only have available to
>   use the starting and ending x,y's (the endpoints) and the associated
>   timestamps of said endpoints. Using these info, we can determine the
>   distance, time difference, and thus velocity or rate of
>   change/movement. We can then make use of that to define the points
>   that are distributed along the line between the 2 endpoints. That's
>   the simple case, although we have multiple lines to traverse.
>
> Then the next step after would be to have to remap some source input
>   that contains a sequence of the endpoints (they only change when
>   reaching the next endpoint, thus I call them in sample code below as
>   the source "template" x/y to be replaced by their derived point
>   distribution x/y equivalent that roughly defines where they should be.
>   e.g. the x/y sequence "1,5;1,5;1,5;1,8;1,8;...." would really be
>   something like this "1,5;1,6;1,7;1,8;..." where we started from 1,5 to
>   move to 1,8 along a line. 1,6 and 1,7 are thus calculated to be moved
>   to at some point traveling from 1,5 to 1,8.

And the code I have for this is below. I'm looking for review of the algorithm for correctness and how to optimize it as I suspect (based on using it to remap x/y's) that it's a bit flawed, and doesn't perfectly distribute points between the endpoints. And I need it to be as accurate as possible.

```
for i in range(len(endpts)):
  if i < len(endpts) - 1:
    ts_diff = abs(endpts[i+1]['ts'] - endpts[i]['ts']) # in seconds, assuming not need convert to ms or ns
    distance = calc_distance(endpts[i]['x'], endpts[i]['y'], endpts[i+1]['x'], endpts[i+1]['y']) # where distance calculated as square root of (diff in x)^2 + (diff in y)^2
    rate = 1 if ts_diff == 0 else float("{0:.2f}".format(distance / float(ts_diff)))

  if endpts[i]['x'] == endpts[i+1]['x'] and endpts[i]['y'] != endpts[i+1]['y']:
    # vertical movement/change (in y)
    direction = 1 if endpts[i]['y'] < endpts[i+1]['y'] else -1
    for j in range(ts_diff+1): # +1 in case ts_diff = 0
      # assume each point along the line between endpt[i] and endpt[i+1] is spaced by ~ 1 second apart in terms of timestamps
      pt_mapping = {'x': endpts[i]['x'], 'y': endpts[i]['y'] + j * rate * direction, 'time_end': endpts[i]['ts'] + (j + 1)}
      distribution_pts.append(pt_mapping)
  elif endpts[i]['x'] != endpts[i+1]['x'] and endpts[i]['y'] == endpts[i+1]['y']:
    # horizontal movement/change (in x)
    direction = 1 if endpts[i]['x'] < endpts[i+1]['x'] else -1
    for j in range(ts_diff+1):
      pt_mapping = {'x': endpts[i]['x'] + j * rate * direction, 'y': endpts[i]['y'], 'time_end': endpts[i]['ts'] + (j + 1)}
      distribution_pts.append(pt_mapping)
  else:
    # diagonal movement/change in both x & y
    direction_x = 1 if endpts[i]['x'] < endpts[i+1]['x'] else -1
    direction_y = 1 if endpts[i]['y'] < endpts[i+1]['y'] else -1
    for j in range(ts_diff+1):
      pt_mapping = {'x': endpts[i]['x'] + j * rate * direction_x, 'y': endpts[i]['y'] + j * rate * direction_y, 'time_end': endpts[i]['ts'] + (j + 1)}
      distribution_pts.append(pt_mapping)

for src_msg in src_msgs:
  target_xy = get_target_xy(get_epoch_sec_timestamp(src_msg['ts'])) # where ts is ISO8601 ts string to convert to sec since epoch
  src_msg['x'] = target_xy['x'] # replacing source template x with derived x
  src_msg['y'] = target_xy['y'] # replacing source template y with derived y

# where we get target x/y by finding 1st distribution pt where
# ts >= the src ts of the pt we're looking at, as a way to check
# how far we've moved along from one endpt to reach another, since
# we have no other "tracking" methods to know that
def get_target_xy(ts):
  for entry in distribution_pts:
    if entry['time_end'] < ts:
      continue
    return entry
  print "Crap, no target xy matched for input time %s" % ts
```